# What the best way to deploy javascript based web app?

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2

I'm a j2ee developer and till now I've deployed web apps in Tomcat, Weblogic and many App Servers, which were completely j2ee based.

Now I'm developing a Javascript based app that uses require js for module, QuickBlox and Firebase JS.

Now what are my options to deploy them so that a user can use them for chatting purpose like via www.chatapp.com

We are using Amazon's cloud platform EC2(I'm new to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org) is the way to go if your application will be a [Single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). NodeJS will give you the ability to manipulate your application on the fly in the server side with pure JavaScript if necessary.

To start with, you can use [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) to serve your files. From ExpressJS documentation:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

The app starts a server and listens on port 3000 for connections.

Read the ExpressJS docs for more information. There is a lot of ways to serve files in NodeJS. You can search for more in [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Comment: What I understood, NodeJS is only Javascript Engine. Then how can it be used as a server? Can I map a domain address too ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase as your backend, and just need to serve your HTML/CSS/JS files to clients, you could simply place those files in an S3 bucket and enable static website hosting.